# Double CTRL+ALT+DEL to type Username in Windows 10

Tags: login, windows-10, windows-registry

Is there a way to bring back the double CTRL+ALT+DEL to make the Windows 10 login screen change from showing the usernames to allowing you to type in a user name?  I know I can modify things so that it ALWAYS makes you type in a username/password but I want the normal behavior to remain (Clicking on a username in the bottom left corner) but have the option to switch so I can type in an account when needed.

I found the fast-user switching program tsdiscon.exe and thought maybe with a hotkey or registry hack, I can create some new key combination that will allow me to type in a username.

Anyone tried or succeeded in this?

Comment: Isn't it so that on windows 10, when the pc is joined to a domain, you basically always have this? You click on the user and type its password for the last logged in user, or you click on the bottom left, other user, and then type in the username and password. I believe this is what you're after, but requires the pc to be joined to a domain. If you allow empty passwords in the domain, and set none, you can just click the user. But the more I think about it, the more I'm thinking this is always there in Windows 10 Pro, regardless of if the pc is domain joined.

Comment: The PC is not domain joined.  When there is only one user account on the PC (one non hidden account) there are no icons on the bottom left, it defaults to a password prompt only.  Hence the need to be able to type a user name

Comment: If you really want this, you may want to consider using a spare pc to install a server edition on it and install a active directory on it, then join the pc to the domain. You can turn off the domain controller after that, but the pc may complain not being able to find the domain controller and sign you in with stored credentials on every boot. You do need to login for every user that you want to login with once though, just so a profile is created, and every once in a while, you may have to fire up the domain to login with each account once, though it may also go great for years.

Comment: You can actually also install VirtualBox on your machine, install Windows Server inside, run it, domain join it and do it that way. Keep in mind that it is a bit more technical to go this route because you have to understand how a domain works. For example, if the account expires, you must login to the non-domain joined account, fire up your virtual box, start the domain controller, switch user, login, switch user, shut down vm, log out, switch user.

Comment: Actually, no... just being domain joined is sufficient but you can still logon using your non-domain account, so then there's no problem of expiration at all. Just join it once to the domain and keep logging in with the old user. You can do this by typing .\username if you switch user and have to type a user.

Comment: LPChip, your method would work in a rough manner...but then I can't switch between the username/password prompt and back to the original login screen with boxes in the bottom left hand corner.  I don't want to permanently switch to having to type in a username.

Comment: I know I can modify the registry to force the login screen to ask for a username rather thank click on one in the bottom left corner, i'm trying to see if I can force that change by using a hotkey and a macro program.  However, it seems to require a reboot each time

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no supported method to do this. [The ctrl-alt-del trick was for Windows XP only](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050914-16/?p=34203).

Comment: Not exactly using the double ctrl-alt-del trick, but windows 10 joined to a pc natively does this. I think this is what OP wants actually, but we lack the information if the pc is domain joined in the first place.